# Are there any decent 3rd party search tools for AD?

Tags: active-directory, security

I'm a bit spoiled by the search tools in SAPs Common User Administration (CUA), and I want to find something similar for Microsoft Active Directory (and, if possible for Information Lifecycle Manager, ILM)

Does anyone know of anything that could help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joeware](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/index.htm) is your friend. Tools written by Directory Services MVP, Joe Richards.